# When need to run a REINDEX in postgres

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I create index when table is created, then insert data into table.
I think when the data in the table has been indexed, no need to run a REINDEX even if i delete or insert new data.
Is this right? Or each time, i need to run a REINDEX.
If I need to import a large amount of data into an existing indexed table should it be better to run a REINDEX?
When should I run a REINDEX?

Please tell me. Thanks!

Comment: Does [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-reindex.html) answer your question?

Comment: Thanks for your support! Does this mean that a REINDEX is not theoretically required...

Comment: If data older than 30 days (about 7000 records) is deleted, is it necessary to run a REINDEX!!?

Comment: As the documentation says, it is not required for any of the situations in your question. The only time I've used it is when building a concurrent index failed. What is more important is vacuum to prevent bloat and analyze to keep the statistics used for query planning up to date. These are also done automatically, but sometimes they need a little tweaking. See https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/optimize-and-improve-postgresql-performance-with-vacuum-analyze-and-reindex-885239781.html And 7000 records is too small to worry about.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You never need to run `REINDEX` to maintain data integrity; all data modifications will update the index.

In normal situations, you never need to `REINDEX`. In particular, bulk insert will never fragment an index more than it was before.

Indexes get bloated if you delete lots of rows or if you run `UPDATE`s faster than autovacuum can keep up with. Then you may need to `REINDEX` them.